# WHERE Inside DB::raw Statement Returning 0

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am trying to do some DB::raw subselects using Laravel but am getting 0 returned, even though if I test it and check the DB there are many entries that match the criteria.

My query looks like this:

```php
$currentUnixTime = time();
    $dt12 = $currentUnixTime - (12*60*60);
    $dt24 = $currentUnixTime - (24*60*60);
    $dt48 = $currentUnixTime - (2*24*60*60);
    $dt168 = $currentUnixTime - (7*24*60*60);

    $updates = DB::table("portals")
        ->select(
              DB::raw("(SELECT COUNT(guid) FROM portals) AS total", []),
              DB::raw("(SELECT COUNT(guid) FROM portals WHERE addedTS > :dt) AS 'dt24'", array(":dt" => $dt24)),
              DB::raw("(SELECT COUNT(guid) FROM portals WHERE addedTS > :dt) AS 'dt48'", array(":dt" => $dt48)),
              DB::raw("(SELECT COUNT(guid) FROM portals WHERE addedTS > :dt) AS 'dt168'", array(":dt" => $dt168)),
              DB::raw("(SELECT COUNT(guid) FROM portals WHERE updatedTS > :dt) AS 'ut168'", array(":dt" => $dt168))
        )
        ->first();
```

The first one `DB::raw("(SELECT COUNT(guid) FROM portals) AS total")` returns a number but the others return 0 which leads me to suspect that it has to do with the inclusion of the `WHERE` statement.

Here is my result:

```
{"total":"47180","dt24":"0","dt48":"0","dt168":"0","ut168":"0"}
```

EDIT: Tried a suggestion from Antony but got the same result.

```php
$updates = DB::table("portals")
        ->select(
            DB::raw("(SELECT COUNT(guid) FROM portals) AS total,
                     (SELECT COUNT(guid) FROM portals WHERE addedTS > ?) AS 'dt24',
                     (SELECT COUNT(guid) FROM portals WHERE addedTS > ?) AS 'dt48',
                     (SELECT COUNT(guid) FROM portals WHERE addedTS > ?) AS 'dt168',
                     (SELECT COUNT(guid) FROM portals WHERE updatedTS > ?) AS 'ut168'",
                     [$dt24, $dt48, $dt168, $dt168]
            )
        )
        ->first();
```

Any ideas?

Thanks! :)

Comment: you can try one query and one parameter...

Comment: Hi @AntonyJack - I'm not quite sure what you mean. I have edited my question with an attempt of what I think you mean.

Comment: did you got the result for 
`$updates = DB::table("portals")
        ->select(
            DB::raw("(SELECT COUNT(guid) FROM portals WHERE addedTS > ?) AS 'dt24'", [$dt24])
        )
        ->first();`

Comment: Ah, I see what you meant. That still returns zero, unfortunately!

Comment: well I think binding problem...

Comment: where is `$dt24` defined in your code...

Comment: I've added some extra code to my question so you can see

Comment: try like `'?' OR ':dt'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

`$updates = DB::table("portals")
        ->selectRaw("Sum(case when addedTS > $dt24  then 1 Else 0 End) as dt24,
          Sum(case when addedTS > $dt48 then 1 else 0 end) as dt48,Sum(1) as total")
        ->first();`

Comment: In your case select query runs for 5 times.. But the above case select query runs for a single time..This is the optimized way for count( counting based on some conditions)

Comment: Hi! Thanks! I managed to modify what you suggested into a solution:

`$queryString = "COUNT(guid) total,
        SUM(CASE WHEN addedTS >= {$dt12} THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) dt12,
        SUM(CASE WHEN addedTS >= {$dt24} THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) dt24,
        SUM(CASE WHEN addedTS >= {$dt48} THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) dt48,
        SUM(CASE WHEN addedTS >= {$dt168} THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) dt168,
        SUM(CASE WHEN updatedTS >= {$dt168} THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ut168";
    $updates = DB::table("portals")
        ->selectRaw($queryString)
        ->first();`

Answer (score 0):

You can try [subqueries](https://laravel-news.com/eloquent-subquery-enhancements) like

```
$updates =  Portal::select(DB::raw('count(*) as total'))->addSelect([
    'dt24' => Portal::where('addedTS', 'dt24')->count(),
    'dt48' => Portal::where('addedTS', 'dt48')->count(),
    'dt168' => Portal::where('addedTS', 'dt168')->count(),
    'ut168' => Portal::where('addedTS', 'ut168')->count(),
])->first();
```

Comment: Hi, I couldn't get this to work! I'm using a SQLite database and not Eloquent so I had trouble converting this.

Comment: Sqlite will work fine with eloquent. Did you check?